# tar function does not work in R

Tags: r, tar

Tar function does not tar files for me in R package..
Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?
My code is below:

```
tar( paste0(repoDir, "repository.tar"), files)
```

where files is something like this:

```
> files
  [1] "/home/rexamine/archivist2/ex/backpack.db"                                 
  [2] "/home/rexamine/archivist2/ex/gallery/019685d39afcc765103c62afe257a0e9.rda"
  [3] "/home/rexamine/archivist2/ex/gallery/019685d39afcc765103c62afe257a0e9.txt"
  [4] "/home/rexamine/archivist2/ex/gallery/08b4bd03f3050067f589eb706e516f28.rda"
```

and `paste0(repoDir, "repository.tar")` is:

```
1] "/home/rexamine/archivist2/ex/repository.tar"
```

After this call there appears `repository.tar` file in given directory, but when I untar this manually it is empty..

Please help me. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Works for me (on windows). What is the size of the tar file? Has R finished tar-ring?

Comment: Yes, R finished tarring. Files have in total 12 000 bytes. I am using Ubuntu. Tar file after taring has 1024 bytes.

Comment: What happens if you call the linux `tar` from the terminal command line?

Comment: Under Windows it does not work neither..

Comment: For this R call, the R `tar` function just makes a call to `Sys.getenv("tar")`. What are those values on your systems? On my system it is at the moment just `""`. There is a somewhat cryptic note in the help file warning us about that.

Comment: It works for me on windows (7).

Comment: On mine it didn't :p

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce your problem and I'm stomped as to what's going astray.